# Is imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation: cropping the original images?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is the UIImage method:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
```

cropping the original image or just rotating it?

Is there a way to display such image without having to display it in my app user interface ?

thanks

Comment: Where do you want it to display if not in the interface?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I don't need to display it, I need to perform some image processing on it. I would like to display it for debug purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, is not going to be cropped, just rotated and scaled by that size:

[UIImage Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCGImage%3ascale%3aorientation%3a)

And, about how to display it without "displaying" it, maybe is a good idea to put the hidden parameter to YES, or set the alpha to 0.0